# Payum: установить свой url для capture

Tags: php, yii2

Я пытаюсь использовать [Payum](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/) для приёма платежей на сайте.

Проблема в том, что непонятно, как поменять capture url. По умолчанию он строится как '.../capture.php', а мне нужно указать там свой url, так как у приложения свои правила роутинга (используется yii2).

Но я совсем не понимаю архитектуру этого пакета. Я посмотрел исходный код, посмотрел существующие расширения для различных фреймворков, увидел, что есть `TokenFactory`, где можно задавать url, но все равно не понял, как именно это делать. Я бы бросил, но количество звездочек на  github проекта намекает мне, что я просто чего-то не знаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в payum задать свои url для capture/done и т. п.?

Подробности:

Инициализация payum:

```
$ymGateway = new \yandexmoney\YandexMoney\Gateway();

$payum = (new PayumBuilder())
    ->addDefaultStorages()
    ->addGateway('yandexKassa', [
        'factory' => 'omnipay',
        'payum.api' => $ymGateway,
    ])
    ->getPayum()
;
```

Prepare:

```
$paymentClass = \Payum\Core\Model\Payment::class;

/** @var \Payum\Core\Payum $payum */
$storage = $payum->getStorage($paymentClass);

$payment = $storage->create();
$payment->setNumber(uniqid());
$payment->setCurrencyCode('EUR');
$payment->setTotalAmount(123); // 1.23 EUR
$payment->setDescription('A description');
$payment->setClientId(234);
$payment->setClientEmail('foo@example.com');

$storage->update($payment);

$captureToken = $payum->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken('yandexKassa', $payment, 'done.php');

die($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
```

Это действие отрабатывает на странице '/pay/prepare'. На выходе получается ссылка '/pay/prepare/capture.php'. Мне нужно, чтобы ссылка была '/pay/capture'.

В каком месте здесь нужно вставить инициализацию `TokenFactory` и как она должна выглядеть, или, если это неправильный способ, что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было задавать свои url?

Comment: По идее все платежные системы просят/требуют создать им отдельные скрипты/страницы, которые будут работать с ними, например, запрос на получение данных, оплату, подтверждение оплаты, проверка платежа, отказ от платежа и т.д. Соответственно, Вы должны сами создать такие обработчики и указать их для платежной системы, куда потом банк будет стучаться для работы с Вашим сайтом.

Comment: @DaemonHK так и есть. Я пытаюсь с помощью payum создать такие обработчики. Но не понимаю, как задать в payum нужное мне формирование url.

Comment: Попробуйте не париться и задать пути от домена, например, `http://site.com/capture/` или `http://site.com/capture.php`

Comment: Дефолтный урл устанавливается только если он не был задан явно. Вот например место где это проверяется в случае Paypal EC: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Action/PurchaseAction.php#L51

Вам всеголишь надо установить это значение на этапе подготовки платежа. 

Стороний вопрос, зачем вам нужен свой урл? Спрашиваю потому что есть ошушение что вы чтото делаете не так.

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar я добавил подробностей в вопрос. Свой url нужен, чтобы когда окажется, что дефолтный url необходимо поменять (а такое случается всегда внезапно и непредсказуемо), чтобы я мог это сделать.

Comment: По идее вы можете\должны менять prepare url и done url но все что посередине вы не должны трогать (capture\authorize и тд). capture url уникальный для каждого платежа скрывает детали чтобы пользователь не мог хакнуть систему и удаляются как только они не нужны

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar я это понимаю, я не планировал менять get-параметры, в которых указан токен. Я хочу только поменять путь на capture

Comment: Тогда надо переопределить token factory

Comment: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/927e067e6a82f3bf7c53c423998713398e16c2e8/src/Payum/Core/PayumBuilder.php#L235

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar вот именно на этом моменте я и споткнулся. Я не понимаю, как правильно создать TokenFactory. Можете подсказать?

Comment: Реализовать интерфейс token factory. Както так https://github.com/Payum/PayumYiiExtension/blob/master/src/Payum/YiiExtension/TokenFactory.php

Answer (score 0):

Had to dig up the code on github to figure it out, but finally found that you can do this in the config stage:

```
$paymentClass = Payment::class;
    $payum = (new PayumBuilder())->addDefaultStorages()
        ->addGateway('aGateway', [
            'factory' => 'offline',
        ])->setGenericTokenFactoryPaths([
            'capture' => 'YourCustomUrl',
        ])->getPayum();
```